# integrating a differential equation with two derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve for y(t) in terms of x(t)?

Consider the following diff equation

```
2y'(t) + y(t) = 2x'(t) - x(t)
```

Thanks

edit: I need the solution in terms of solely the equation, I cannot have x'(t) in the solution - it must be of form y(t) = T[x(t)]

Comment: How do you do this without having x'(t) in the answer? I want y(t) in terms of solely x(t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiplicate equation with integrating factor $\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{t}{2}}$. Then you can express $y(t)$ as a function of $x(t)$:

$$(y e^\frac{t}{2})'=e^\frac{t}{2}(x'(t)-\frac{x(t)}{2})$$ 
and
$$y(t)=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\int e^\frac{t}{2}(x'(t)-\frac{x(t)}{2}) dt$$

Comment: How can i simplify it such that there is no x'(t) in the equation?

Comment: By using partial integration, you get: $\int e^\frac{t}2 x'(t) dt=e^\frac{t}{2}x(t)-\frac{1}{2}\int e^\frac{t}{2}x(t) dt$ and finally $y(t)=x(t)-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\int e^\frac{t}{2} x(t) dt$